# Angular2: Set a component's templateUrl in code

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Let's say I have the following static HTML pages, examples:

../project_dir/help/help_files/learn-how-to-bake.html

../project_dir/help/help_files/learn-how-to-cook-salmon.html

etc...

I have a component called "HelpComponent" and in this component I would like to set the templateUrl based on the page that I'm at, example:

```
if (this.router.url == '/cooking/pies')
    templateUrl = '../project_dir/help/help_files/learn-how-to-bake.html'
else if (this.router.url == '/cooking/salmon')
    templateUrl = '../project_dir/help/help_files/learn-how-to-cook-salmon.html'
```

Is there a way to dynamically set a component's templateUrl in Angular2?

Comment: Your code should be deployed using an AOT build, and you absolutely can not do this with an AOT build. I don't know 100% for sure if there's a hacky way to have dynamic templateUrls with the JIT compiler, but I know that you shouldn't be doing this is in the first place. There are plenty of non-hacky Angular ways that you could accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @matmo Can you give me some ideas to accomplish this ?

Comment: The simplest way is to make a component out of each of those templates, and then in your HelpComponent's template you just conditionally (ngIf) render them based on the router url. Any reason that won't work?

Comment: @matmo I have 20 templates, I was trying to avoid having to create a component for each one of them but I guess that's the simplest way. oh well.

Comment: @matmo is there a 'hacky' way to do this?

Comment: Unless you statically define the templateUrl, you're always going to have to have a performance penalty. If you're fine with that, you could just make an http call to fetch the proper template html file when HelpComponent loads up and then just add it to your view with a binding to innerHTML, i.e. `<div [innerHTML]="myFetchedHtml"></div>`.

Comment: I tried that but it always returns a 404 not found error... for some reason it can't load static html files located in the project:     http.get("../project_dir/help/help_files/learn-how-to-bake.html").subscribe((html:any) => this.myFetchedHtml = html);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163758/discussion-between-matmo-and-eric-bergman).